# Display lists of strings as columns on VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

So if I have lets say three string lists, how can I have each string appear as a column in a table on a VF page? Is it possible to have a PageBlockTable or would I have to build it another way?

```
List<String> firstName = new list<String> { 'John' , 'Amy' , 'Andrew'};
List<String> lastName = new list<String> { 'Smith' , 'Williams' , 'Jones'};
List<String> cityName = new list<String> { 'New York' , 'LA' , 'Miami'};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you have a helper variable to access the indices. This example presumes that all lists are to be of equal length:

```
public class DemoController {
    public string[] firstName { get; set; }
    public string[] lastName { get; set; }
    public string[] cityName { get; set; }
    public Integer[] indexes { get; set; }
    public DemoController() {
        firstName = new string[] { 'John' , 'Amy' , 'Andrew'};
        lastName = new string[] { 'Smith' , 'Williams' , 'Jones'};
        cityName = new string[] { 'New York' , 'LA' , 'Miami'};
        indexes = new Integer[] { 0, 1, 2 };
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="DemoController">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!indexes}" var="index">
            <apex:column headerValue="First Name" value="{!firstName[index]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Last Name" value="{!lastName[index]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="City" value="{!cityName[index]}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

There are other ways to arrange this behavior, such as with CSS or potentially messing around with an `apex:variable`, but this technique is the one I generally regard as the safest method, even if it does use a bit more view state.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for sfdcfox's answer as it directly answers the question.

Just want to point out that in general, it is best to avoid [arrays of items that have to be consistently indexed](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/), which in this case would mean changing to something like this:

```
public class DemoController {

    public Item {

        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string cityName { get; set; }

        private Item(string firstName, string lastName, string cityName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.cityName = cityName;
        }
    }

    public Item[] items { get; set; }

    public DemoController() {
        items = new Item[] {
            new Item('John', 'Smith', 'New York'),
            new Item('Amy', 'Williams', 'LA'),
            new Item('Andrew', 'Jones', 'Miami')
        };
    }
}
```

and:

```
<apex:page controller="DemoController">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!items}" var="item">
            <apex:column headerValue="First Name" value="{!item.firstName}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Last Name" value="{!item.lastName}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="City" value="{!item.cityName}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```